How to fit rectangles over a point cloud distributed in a plane?
We have a point cloud which has points which lie in the same plane. They are distributed similar to the red dots in the image below, we want to fit rectangles denoted by the yellow boxes. These rectangles should be fitted in a way that they should cover the entire distribution of points in least number of instances/rectangles as tightly around the points as possible.

The Blue box denotes a minimal bounding box which we can easily obtained using something like open3d's get_minimal_oriented_bounding_box() function.
Planar patch detection by Arujo And Oliveira can be a good approach to solve this in cases where the three sets of points (sets separated by yellow boxes) are disjoint (have some separation in between them).
Using a octree to decimate data into small chunks and then drawing bounding boxes around them is another approach, but might produce many smaller rectangles which is not a optimal result.

What's an "incorrect box" in your sentence "incorrect boxes at the intersections of two yellow boxes"? In your image example, how did you decide whether this intersection between the two leftmost yellow rectangles should belong to the vertical or the horizontal box?

@Stef I have modified the question, planar patch detection algorithm will generally give results similar to the blue box. The intersection can belong to any of the two boxes, in the leftmost rectangles, but in the case of rightmost, it should belong to the vertical box as it will produce a result where we fit the least number of rectangles over the distribution.

Have you tried using k-means clustering to partition your data and then computing the bounding box of each cluster? You can run it for a few different number of clusters (initial parameter) and then compare the total surface covered by your bounding boxes.
For example, scikit-learn provides a fairly easy to implement KMeans algorithm.
Also, would it be possible to provide an example of the data you're dealing with?

With a straightforward k-means you will probably end up with non-rectangle clusters such as: https://i.imgur.com/Q9DeynU.png

Indeed it is difficult to guarantee that clusters would be rectangle.

Another kind of algorithm that I can think of is RANSAC, but the number of inliers would not be a good measure of fit. You may try to divide this by the candidate rectangle area but you would only end-up with small rectangles with high points density.
Looking at your example in detail, it somehow reminds me of the 2D object detection problem. Maybe a path worth trying?

@Stef you're right clustering algorithms won't be efficient in solving this problem, I've experimented with a bunch of them, the approach that i am using right now is to extract a Skeleton and using it to extract a estimate length and then applying pca along center of the length to calculate the width. I have tried converting it to a 2-d object detection problem, something like contour detection might work but it's easier to work with the topology/skeleton.
